# Не устанавливается laravel через composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Система Windows 10. PHP версия 8.1.9, composer 2.5.3.
Пытаюсь установить командой:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example-app
```

На что выходит ошибка что у меня не соответствует версия php, хотя версия больше 7.4 явно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cannot use laravel/laravel's latest version v8.0.0 as it requires php ^7.3 which is not satisfied by your platform.

In CreateProjectCommand.php line 421:

Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8.0 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.

Comment: `^7.4` это не просто выше 7.4, а в пределах мажорной версии, то есть до `<8.0`

Answer (score 0):

хм.... Не понимаю, у меня правда Linux, но вот принудительно установка 8-ой версии Лары, через композер для PHP 8.1.9 (так-то уже 10-я версия Laravel тянется по умолчанию) :

```
$ cd tmp
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example-app
$ cd example-app
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 8.83.27
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.9 (cli) ...
```